# Italian citizenship

Tags: italy, language-test

My husband is U.K. citizen but he is working and we reside in Italy last 5 years. He wants to apply for Italian citizenship but his Italian is almost non existent. Does he have to pass Italian language test to get citizenship?

Comment: Are you an Italian citizen? I think the answer to your question depends on that. According to [Citizenship](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/italiani_nel_mondo/serviziconsolari/cittadinanza.html), acquiring Italian citizenship by marriage to an Italian citizen does not seem to require a language test. But it may be more difficult for him to obtain Italian citizenship if you are not Italian.

Comment: We are both have  U.K. citizenship but have Italian residence.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is too late for this but anyway, as EU citizen the only requirement is 4 year residence. There is no formal requirement for Italian knowledge, but all the documentation and the forms to fill will be in Italian. This is the only official info in English I could find [The Italian citizenship - www.integrazionemigranti.gov.it](http://www.integrazionemigranti.gov.it/en/legal-framework/domestic-law/Pages/The-Italian-citizenship.aspx)